# Laravel. Sort by user role, relations

Tags: php, laravel

I want to sort the users by role and I would like the user to have another role disappear.

**Controller**

```
$users = User::with(['roles' => function($query) {
    $query->where('name','=','Admin');
}])->get();
```

**View**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($user->roles as $role)
                {{$role->name}}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

It does not pass the role, but displays the user data. I only want user data from the `Admin` role. I don't want to display `John Doe`.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter by relation using `whereHas`

Try the following

```
$users = User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Admin');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($query) {
                $query->where('name','=','Admin');

            }])->get()->sortByDesc('roles.name');
```

You can find the explanation of sortBy or sortByDesc in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortbydesc

Comment: ok, yout problem was with() , the with function return all model, you can see difference here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/problem-with-the-eager-loading-of-laravel-eloquent-orm?page=1

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
 $users = User::with(['roles' => function($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('name')
                   ->where(['name'=>'Admin']);
        }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$users = User::User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function($query) {
                $query->where('name','Admin');
            }])->get();
```

OR you can try fluent way like:

**Controller**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->select('users.id as Id','users.name as userName','users.email as email','roles.name as roleName')
->join('roles','roles.user_id','=','users.id')
->where('roles.name','=','admin')
->get();
```

**View**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->Id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->userName}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->roleName}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: sry, miss click, i try this for one moment. Wait, is not my down vote xd